# How do I get the cleanup badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have seen first rollback awarded to few users in 
TSE,  I just want to know that:

How do they normally achieve that?

Comment: @ pnuts I have seen this, just want to how it works? When do you achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding badge [Cleanup](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) is given to users who have used the roll back option for the first time. What is roll back? Well, if you check the edit history of a post, you will note a set of links next to each version: `source`, `edit` and `link` on all versions and `rollback` on all but the final one.

[image: Image of a random posts edit history]

Clicking on `source` will give you the raw input of any past version. `edit` will allow you to edit it *and save the edits as the current version of the post.* `link` provides a convenient way to link to old versions of a post and `rollback` re-saves an old version of the post, overwriting any changes that have happened since.

Every time a user uses said `rollback` option the first time, they are awarded the cleanup badge.

Comment: Nice one that's what exactly I wanted to know